# How to convert a list of binary to char?

Tags: erlang

I would like to convert a list of zeros and ones to a char.
example :

```
bitToChar([1,0,0,0,1,0,1]) = $Q
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$0` to each of them (to make it a string with `$0`s and `$1`s), reverse the list, and use `list_to_integer/2` with base `2`:

```
1> list_to_integer(lists:reverse([N + $0 || N <- [1,0,0,0,1,0,1]]), 2) == $Q.
true
```

You can also use `lists:foldl`. The code is slightly longer but it doesn't use `list_to_binary`:

```
1> element(2, lists:foldl(fun(Digit, {Mul, Acc}) -> {Mul * 2, Acc + Digit * Mul} end, {1, 0}, Xs)) == $Q.              true
```

This is basically equivalent to doing: `1 * 1 + 0 * 2 + 0 * 4 + 0 * 8 + 1 * 16 + 0 * 32 + 1 * 64`.

Comment: I added another way using `lists:foldl/3`.

Comment: but i need to print the result like that i dont want to compare, in the console it should be $Q.

Comment: $Q and 81 are the same integer, $Q is just an easier form to remember. In erlang the character type doesn't exist, it is an integer in the range 0-255. if you want to print it as a character you must use one of the io (or io_lib) functions with the appropriate format (for example `io:format("~c~n",[81])`) - note that with this example you will not get the leading '$'

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it is to use a [bit string comprehension](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84348):

```
X = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
<<C:7>> = << <<Bit:1>> || Bit <- lists:reverse(X) >>,
$Q == C.
```

That is, pick one element at a time from the list, and use each element as a bit in the binary being built, and finally extract a seven-bit number into the variable `C`.

Comment: Just curious: Is there a way to do this for arbitrary sized lists in a one liner (i.e. not storing `Length = length(X).` in a variable and then using it in `C:Length`)? I tried `binary:decode_unsigned/1` but it doesn't accept bitstrings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Q = lists:foldr(fun(X,Acc) -> X + (Acc bsl 1) end, 0,[1,0,0,0,1,0,1]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$Q` is integer value all you have to do is use in `BitToChar` conversion from binary based number to decimal based number.

Simplest conversion is:

```
to_decimal(X) ->
  to_decimal(lists:reverse(X), 1, 0).

% you can validate that if H = 1 then add, if other not but I omitted this validation
to_decimal([H | T], Times, Acc) ->
  to_decimal(T, 2 * Times, H * Times + Acc);

to_decimal([], _Times, Acc) -> Acc.
```

And then it will return integer. 
In your case:

```
> $Q = 81. 
81

> $Q == 81.
true
```